# Microsoft personal accounts scope is limited to User.Read

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have registered an application via Microsoft's AAD Portal. This application is supposed to be accessed by anyone. So I have set `signInAudience: AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` in my manifest.

My application needs two scopes:

- `User.Read`
- `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`

When I test the application using my Microsoft developer account (which is a part of the organisation in which this application is created), I am able to consent to both scopes.

[image]

However, when using my personal email ID, I am asked to consent only `User.Read` scope.

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` is not supported for personal accounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: Could you please help with this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546226/allow-anyone-to-join-or-start-microsoft-teams-meeting