# Allow anyone to join or start microsoft teams meeting

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-teams, msal.js

I have registered an application using Microsoft's developer program. The application is supposed to create MS Teams meeting URLs for any tenant. Below is my current flow:

1. User from tenant/organization X (let's call him UserX) authorizes my app and gives permission to two scopes: `User.Read` and `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`.
2. UserX creates a MS Teams URL.
3. UserX shares the generated URL with the participants, where the user is not required to join the meeting.

Problem I'm facing: When anyone(both personal or any other organization/tenant account) tries to join the URL shared by UserX, they are not able to start or join the meeting. Microsoft says,

> When the meeting starts, we'll let people know you're waiting

The only way I can start the meeting is when anyone from tenant/organization X signs-in and starts the meeting. I am even passing `lobbyBypassSettings` but have got no success.

Below is my code in `python` using `msal`.

```
def schedule_interview():
    token = get_auth_token()
    client_instance = retrieveClientInstance()

    refresh_token = client_instance.acquire_token_by_refresh_token(
        refresh_token=token.refresh_token,
        scopes=['User.Read','OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite']
    )

    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + refresh_token['access_token'], 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    
    meeting_data = {
        "subject": "My Awesome Meeting",
        "lobbyBypassSettings":{ "scope": "everyone"}
         }
    response = requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings', json=meeting_data,headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    return data['joinWebUrl']
```

Comment: Please review the documentation for the onlineMeetings API. Note, this API does not support personal accounts, and that you may need to specify the meeting start time. https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Could you please refer below document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0